# web page navigation not working when link is clicked

Tags: html, navigation

I have a web page that is a table of contents and the page navigation is not working. Here is the html:

```
<a name="top_of_page">Create Account</a>

<a href="#top_of_page">top</a>
```

When i click on the top of page link nothing happens. Am i doing something wrong? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is not the correct attribute to use. Use `id` instead.

```html
<a id="top_of_page">Create Account</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="#top_of_page">top</a>
```

Comment: are you sure that the code looks exactly the same...try the snippet one more time.

Comment: Sorry had bug in my css working now thanks. Will verify when site allows.